# Get total and partial count of something on database - SQL SERVER

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

I just neEd to get the total count of products by category and also the count of product which have price >= 5 by category

This is what I need

[image]

You can use my example **[ON SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/4a5b9/1)**

Thank you very much!

Comment: How do you get the `id_order` value you show here from the data in the SQL Fiddle data?

Comment: It's probably an identity column. It shouldn't be needed to get the data that is needed.

Answer (score 2):

```
select  id_category,
count(1) as qty_products, 
count(case when product_price>5 then 1 end) as [qty_products>5]
from orders
group by id_category
```

It should give you count of products per category. I'm not sure what do you want to display as "id_order" though ... If it's just row number, then you can do something like

```
select  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY id_category) as rownum,id_category,
count(1) as qty_products, 
count(case when product_price>5 then 1 end) as [qty_products>5]
from orders
group by id_category
```

Comment: +1 for the `ROW_NUMBER()` to get the output the OP requested.

Comment: That´s the answer! Thanks! =D

Answer (score 0):

All:

```
SELECT
id_category,
count(*) AS COUNT
FROM orders
GROUP BY id_category
```

Output:

```
ID_CATEGORY COUNT
1           12
2           10
5           6
```

Only price >=5:

```
SELECT
id_category,
COUNT(*) AS COUNT
FROM orders
WHERE product_price >=5
GROUP BY id_category
```

Output:

```
ID_CATEGORY COUNT
1           10
2           7
5           3
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT ID_CATEGORY, COUNT(ID_PRODUCT) AS NoOfProducts, 
SUM(CASE WHEN PRODUCT_PRICE > 5 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS ProductsAbove5 
FROM Orders GROUP BY ID_CATEGORY
```

Fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/4a5b9/14)

However, you can not get **Id_Order** field as you have to group by **category**.

Answer (score 0):

```
select
  id_category, 
  count(id_product) as CountAll, 
  count(case when product_price > 5 then 1 else 0 end) as CountGreaterThan5
from orders
group by id_category
```